# ggforce adds horizontal zoom background when "horizontal = FALSE"

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

Consider this relatively simple plot (the red color was added only to demonstrate the problem a bit better).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, colour = Species)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_zoom(x = Species == "versicolor") +
    theme(zoom = element_rect(fill = "red"))
```

[image]

Now I want to adjust the `ylim` of the zoomed part (the lower plot).

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, colour = Species)) +
    geom_point() +
    facet_zoom(
        x = Species == "versicolor",
        ylim = c(0.5, 2.5),
        horizontal = FALSE
    ) +
    theme(zoom = element_rect(fill = "red"))
```

[image]

So we add `ylim` and `horizontal = FALSE` cause we only want vertical zoom. However, `ggforce` adds a horizontal zoom indicator nonetheless (the red horizontal bar). Is it possible to get rid of that? So that we only get the vertical zoom indicator like above?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO you misunderstood the working of `horizontal`. As I read the docs, `horizontal` is used to the position the zoom panel (see `?facet_zoom`):

> How should the zoom panel be positioned relative to the full data panel?

Moreover using `x = Species == "versicolor"` you specify that you want to zoom the range of x to the versicolor data. And when adding `ylim` you additionally add a zoom of the y axis. And that's what the "zoom indicators" are showing.

But a fix would be to set the fill color for the unwanted "zoom indicator" to `NA` via theme options:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, colour = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_zoom(
    x = Species == "versicolor",
    ylim = c(0.5, 2.5),
    horizontal = FALSE
  ) +
  theme(zoom.x = element_rect(fill = "red"), zoom.y = element_rect(fill = NA))
```

[image]